# How can I select the lowest number from multiple tables in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

```
Lets say I have three tables:
Table1
Id  Score
1     2
2     5
3     5

Table2
Id  Score
1     1
2     2
3     3

Table3
Id  Score
1     4
2     4
3     2
```

How can I get the lowest value for each Id from the three tables? So when I execute the query it would post something like this:

```
Id   LowestScore
1       1
2       2
3       2
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `UNION` to combine the records from the three tables and wrap it on a subquery then use `MIN()` to get the lowest score for each `ID`.

```
SELECT  ID, MIN(Score) Score
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  ID, Score FROM Table1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  ID, Score FROM Table2
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  ID, Score FROM Table3
        ) sub
GROUP   BY ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15bbd/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ SCORE ║
╠════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║     1 ║
║  2 ║     2 ║
║  3 ║     2 ║
╚════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Hey THANKS!!, one question thought...some scores are null, how can I take them as 0 and if thats the case select it as the lowest score

Comment: use `COALESCE`, example: `SELECT  ID, COALESCE(Score, 0) Score FROM Table1`